# RabbitMQ - Know which message is Acked

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to publish two messages and receiv Ack/Nack.  Below is my code:

```
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            {
                using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
                {
                    channel.BasicAcks += channel_BasicAcks;
                    channel.BasicNacks += channel_BasicNacks;

                    channel.QueueDeclare("test", durable, false, false, null);
                    channel.ConfirmSelect();

                    var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                    properties.SetPersistent(true);

                    string message = "Hello World!";
                    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                    channel.BasicPublish("", "test", properties, body);
                    channel.BasicPublish("", "test", properties, body);
                    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);

                    channel.WaitForConfirmsOrDie();
                }
            }
```

My Ack/Nack events

```
 static void channel_BasicNacks(object sender, RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicNackEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    static void channel_BasicAcks(object sender, RabbitMQ.Client.Events.BasicAckEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

For those two messages, I perfectly received two Ack event calls. I'm even able to e.DeliveryTag as 1 and 2 (I hope those are sequence numbers of the messages I processed).

I want to know which message is acked / nacked more precisely rather than depending on Sequence number to do certain actions.

Is there a way that I can append a unique identifier to message and get the same id back in Ack / Nack event args to verify that a particular message is acked / nacked.  Thanks for your pointers.

Let us say for example, I have been polling a folder and reading list of files from that folder and publishing the content to a queue.  A file might be acked; another might be nacked; I want to know which file is acked or nacked so that I can move file to respective success / failed folders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMQP's `Basic.Ack` method does not have room for user-specified content, so no, you can't use an arbitrary ID.

However, you can [query the next sequence ID](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.6.1/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.6.1-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.html#property-P:RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.NextPublishSeqNo) which will be used for the next publish, and maintain a map locally to associate messages to their sequence ID.

Sequence IDs start at 1, so `NextPublishSeqNo()` will return 1 before any publish, 2 after the first publish and so on.

Comment: In that case, I think I have to assign sequence to my files at run time and remember that sequence until I get all acks/nacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional parameters to the event handler and know which message is not acknowledged

```
channel.BasicNacks += (sender, e) => channel_BasicNacks(sender, e, message);
```

Event Handler

```
private static void channel_BasicNacks(object sender, BasicNackEventArgs e,string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```